# Retained children - have to release?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Say I got my CCSprite for player, and then another CCSprite for a health bar.

The health CCSprite is a child of the player CCSprite.

For certain reasons, I decided to retain the health bar, like

```
[healthBarSprite retain];
```

My question is: since I retained the health bar, I should run

```
[healthBarSprite release];
```

At some point, right?

Here's a thing: the health bar is retained, but the player sprite is not. So the only thing I release is the health bar?

**If** the player sprite was actually retained, upon releasing it, is the health bar automatically released as well or I have to release it first and then the player?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to send release to the health bar. Whether the player sprite releases the health bar is not something you need to worry about; if it releases it, the intent is balance out a retain that it has made internally. All you have to worry about is balancing the retain calls that *you* have made.

To illustrate, it is very likely that the player sprite retains its children as they are added and releases them when they are removed, but regardless, that is an implementation detail of the CCSprite. It will worry about balancing retain calls that it has made, and you worry about balancing yours.